# how to set the n parameter to everything in the list in difflib.get_close_matches()

Tags: python, difflib

I want to use the `difflib.get_close_matches()` function on a dictionary and after searching I found that the default number of close matches is 3 but I want it to find everything that is a close match to the input. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Does passing `n=float('inf')` not "work"?

Comment: No, I tried it and it showed me a huge bulk of error and the only thing I understood was this:
```TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method```

Comment: Ah, I see. Then `n=None` will probably work.